# Programa de distinción de listas menor a mayor, mayor a menor y otro. No corre en Python

Tags: python, ordenar

**Hola buenas, estaba intentando poder hacer un programa que puede diferenciar si los números de una lista esta en orden: mayor a menor, menor a mayor y desordenado(ninguna de las otras opciones).
Pero primordialmente ahora con mi código el programa corre pero no imprime nada**

```
 x=0
lista=[1,2,3]
aux=[]
if lista[x] < lista[x+1]:
    aux = lista.sort()
    if lista == aux:
        print("La lista esta ordenada de menor a mayor")
elif lista[x] > lista[x+1]:
    aux = lista.sort()
    aux.reverse()
    if lista == aux:
        print('La lista esta ordenada de mayor a menor')
else:
    print("La lista esta desordenada")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Si se vale usar [sorted()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted), entonces el problema ya está resuelto.

Si el *ordenamiento ascendente* es igual a la `lista`, está ordenado de menor a mayor. Si el *ordenamiento en reverso* es igual a la `lista`, entonces está ordenado de mayor a menor. Si no cumple ninguna, entonces está desordenada.

```
if(sorted(lista) == lista):
    print("La lista esta ordenada de menor a mayor")
elif(sorted(lista, reverse=True) == lista):
    print('La lista esta ordenada de mayor a menor')
else:
    print("La lista esta desordenada")
```

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

El método `sort()` para listas, ordena la lista donde el método ha sido llamado y como todas las funciones que hacen mutaciones (Cambios) a las listas devuelve `None`

Lo que puedes hacer es utilizar el método `sorted()` y pasar la lista ordenada a tu variable `aux`

```
aux = sorted(lista)
```

Por otra parte, el `else` que evalúa si la lista está desordenada no se ejecuta a menos que pongas dos valores iguales como primer y segundo elementos de tu lista, si los agregas a tus `if` y `elif` entonces si evaluará si está desordenada la lista

Utilizando tu código como base y con los comentarios anteriores el ejemplo sería:

```
x=0
lista=[1,3,2]
aux=[]
if lista[x] < lista[x+1]:
    aux = sorted(lista)
    if lista == aux:
        print("La lista esta ordenada de menor a mayor")
    else:
        print("La lista esta desordenada")
elif lista[x] > lista[x+1]:
    aux = sorted(lista)
    aux.reverse()
    if lista == aux:
        print('La lista esta ordenada de mayor a menor')
    else:
        print("La lista esta desordenada")
```

Otra solución más simple podría ser:

```
x=0
lista=[3,1,2]
aux = sorted(lista)

if lista == aux:
    print("La lista esta ordenada de menor a mayor")
elif lista == aux[::-1]:
    print('La lista esta ordenada de mayor a menor')
else:
    print("La lista esta desordenada")
```

Answer (score 0):

Una solución simple, que no requiere el uso de `sort`, `sorted` ni otra función. Valida para listas con más de un elemento:

```
def comparar(a, b):
    if a < b:
        return 1
    if a > b:
        return -1
    return 0 # Iguales

def descubrir_orden(lista):
    # La primera comparación puede dar 1, -1, 0
    orden = comparar(lista[0], lista[1])

    for i in range(1, len(lista)):
        nuevo = comparar(lista[i-1], lista[i])

        if orden == 0: # Los primeros valores son todos iguales
            orden = nuevo

        if nuevo: # Sólo si estos valores son distintos
            if nuevo != orden:
                return None  # Lista no está ordenada

    # Llegamos al final con todo en orden
    return orden
```

La idea es tener una comparación entre valores `a` y `b` que produzca 1, -1 o cero según sea `a > b`, `a < b` o `a == b`.

Luego vamos comparando valores a lo largo de la lista. En tanto el orden de los dos primeros valores se mantenga, la lista está ordenada igual. Tan pronto se encuentren dos valores que den un orden distinto, se retorna `None`, lo que señala que la lista no está ordenada.

El único caso especial es cuando hay valores iguales. En este simplemente se omite la revisión y se sigue hasta encontrar un par desigual.

Paso extra: los dos primeros valores pueden ser iguales, en cuyo caso el orden se determina más adentro de la lista.

#### Demo

```
tests = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
    [1, 5, 4, 2, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
    [1, 2, 2, 2, 3],
    [1, 2, 2, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
]

for test in tests:
    print(test, descubrir_orden(test))
```

produce:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 1
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1] -1
[1, 5, 4, 2, 1] None
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2] 1
[1, 2, 2, 2, 3] 1
[1, 2, 2, 1, 0] None
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1] 0      

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Gracias! Al no usarse métodos, esta forma seria mas eficiente (en rapidez) para cuando se analizan grandes cantidades de números, verdad?

Comment: Este método es de O(n). En el peor de los casos hace una sola pasada por la lista completa. Si la lista está desordenada, aborta tan pronto encuentre el primer par fuera de orden. La otras propuestas requieren ordenar la lista completa primero y comparar después.